# Facebook login callback not called

Tags: facebook, angularjs

I'm trying to use the FB api for login on an app built with angularjs. I'm using the [angular-facebook](https://github.com/Ciul/angular-facebook) library. It works, but the issue is that once the user authorized the app, the callback is not called. So the popup window is not closed, and the only solution for the user is to reload the page. How can I fix this?

```
$scope.login = function() {
    Facebook.login(function(response) {
        // this is never called ;_;
        if (response.status == 'connected') {
          // I need to do stuff here
        }
      }, {scope: 'email,user_birthday,user_likes'});
};
```

Comment: I am using the exact same function and it works fine for me. Can you limit your scope to only email and try and see if it is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

IF you want more detail information on how to use AngularJS with FacebookAPI, this might be helpful:

http://www.boynux.com/angularjs-facebook-integration/

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Based on the angular-facebook documentation shouldn't your code look like this?

```
$scope.login = function() {
    Facebook.login(function(response) {
      // Do something with response. Don't forget here you are on Facebook scope so use $scope.$apply
    });
  };
```

With the Facebook.login function wrapped within a $scope.login function?

Comment: It is, I forgot to copy that part of the code, sorry. I edited my question

Comment: Is the $scope.login function being executed?

Comment: Yes it is, `$scope.login` is executed, the popup opens but the callback is not run

Comment: have you tried adjusting your json object you are sending to the FaceBook API to only send email? like, {scope: 'email'}

Comment: yeah with or without the informations it's always the same

Comment: Take a look at your console network traffic/responses. Perhaps that can clue you in.